# How can I fix Malformed line (54) when gedit wont load?

Tags: command-line, gui, gedit, synaptic

Malformed line (54) error message `gedit` not running, cannot fix as line editor will not load.

I  cannot load any new software or programs.

`gedit` worked before when I was in dual boot but I wiped the detested windows 10, in doing so and moving partitions I had to reinstall ubuntu from thumb drive.

When I started to try to load previously running programs that is when the trouble started.

I dont know if my hand stuttered and placed an extra character somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Use `nano` then edit and press Ctrl + x then y to save and exit

Comment: still working on it. (I'm a nurse not a programmer, learning as I go)

Comment: got into nano, but edit didnt do anything, looking at commands on bottom of terminal

Comment: use it like so `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` isn't a user owned file, so you need to 'elevate' your privileges using `sudo` before the command to edit that file (or most files in fact outside your user directory).  eg. `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: still working now I have ** (org.gnome.gedit:8932): WARNING **: 18:55:34.052: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (org.gnome.gedit:8932): WARNING **: 18:55:34.052: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal.
2. Insert the command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, will ask for your password.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>¹ and insert the number of the line: 54. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   **Anything which doesn't fit this format is incorrect**.

   ```
   # Comment, marked by a line starting with '#'
   deb http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
   deb-src http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
   ```

   The URL, distribution and components will be different. It does not necessarily have to have 3 components.
4. Correct the line, and once corrected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (saves the file) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (exits `nano`).
5. Run `sudo apt update` to check the problem has been solved.

---

<sup>¹You may have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to get the `_`. I can't be sure because I use a spanish keyboard.</sup>

Comment: Thank you everyone, I finally got it.

Comment: PS Schrodigerscatcuriosity love your screenname too